# Javascript functions not working in segments of the site obtained through PHP require

Tags: javascript, php, require

I have some `<script type="text/javascript">` functions in the `<head>` of my site and i have segments of the site that are obtained through PHP `require`, those functions apply to various things some that are already on the same file the functions are in and others that are obtained through `require`, the functions work properly in those segments that are already on the `<body>` right from the start but do not work in those that are obtained through the `require`.

I tried relocating the  at the end of the  to see if it was a issue with the loading order of the elements but it made no difference the functions still dont work.

As always any kind of help is greatly appreacited and thanks for your time.

**As per request below is the code**

The below code resides in the `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHide() {
        var radioDel = document.getElementById("radDel");
        var radioRet = document.getElementById("radRet");

        if (radioDel.checked) {
            document.getElementById("dir").style.display = "flex";
            document.getElementById("diaEn").style.display = "flex";
            document.getElementById("direccion").required = true;
            document.getElementById("radRet").required = false;
        }

        if (radioRet.checked) {
            document.getElementById("dir").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("diaEn").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("direccion").required = false;
            document.getElementById("radDel").required = false;
        }
    }       
</script>
```

The below code resides in the `<body>` and the fucntions work in it:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="radios" id="radRet" type="radio" value="Retira" onclick="showHide()" required>
                <label for="radRet" class="form-check-label font-weight-bold">Retiro personalmente</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="radios" id="radDel" type="radio" value="Delivery" onclick="showHide()" required>
                <label for="radDel" class="form-check-label font-weight-bold">Entrega</label>
                <small id="diaEn" class="form-text text-muted" style="display:none;">Todas las entregas se hacen con Rappi</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

The below code is obtained through `<?php require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/fieldset.php'; ?>` and the functions do not work in it:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="radios" id="radRet" type="radio" value="Retira" onclick="showHide()" required>
                <label for="radRet" class="form-check-label font-weight-bold">Retiro personalmente</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="radios" id="radDel" type="radio" value="Delivery" onclick="showHide()" required>
                <label for="radDel" class="form-check-label font-weight-bold">Entrega</label>
                <small id="diaEn" class="form-text text-muted" style="display:none;">Todas las entregas se hacen con Rappi</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Hi, you should put the code so we can try it to maybe catch the problem.

Comment: Clients javascript knows nothing about the existence of php. Put the code, we find the real reason.

Comment: At the same time is only one code block on page, right? So only once id `radRet`.

Comment: No, @M1K1O, there's the one residing in the **<body>** and that obtained through the PHP **require**, your comment made me realize this, that the id is therefore duplicated once the the **require** is done. I feel kind of stupid now but this has to be the issue right?, i been sitting in front of the computer coding for 15hs straight...

Comment: Yes. That'd be it. No duplicate ids. Solution would be: Pass distinct ID via function parameter, refference that element relatively or change it in PHP.

Comment: Thanks a lot @M1K1O, i do not know how to set your comment as the solution for my question but it definetly is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDs `radRet` and `radDel` are being duplicated.

- Pass distinct ID via function parameter. `showHide(id1, id2)`
- Refference that element relatively.
- Change your ID in PHP.